# how to log all properties of the reqest object in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to learning node.js and curious about what kind of data that req parameter would have while any request hit the server. I have tried `For` loop, but it doesn't seem to logging anything.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function( req, res){
  for (var key in req) {
    if (req.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + req[key]);
    }
}

      res.end("Hi there \n");
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server on 3000');
});
```

Comment: Don't. Just use `console.log(req)` and it'll log as much data as it can. If you need even more inspection, then it's time to learn how to [use the `debugger` keyword and `node --inspect ...`](https://medium.com/@voonminghann/breakpoint-debugging-in-node-js-using-inspect-in-terminal-c6779f5fea4c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log the object itself to the console, and node will take care of this for you.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  console.log(req)
  res.end("Hi there \n");
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server on 3000');
});
```

Gets you:

```
$ node script.js 
Server on 3000
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code can help you:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req, null, 4));
```